# How to call method/variable of one eclipse project to another eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two Projects in eclipse and I simply tried to call method of one project to another but not able to do it even if I set up the whole flow of project setup using properties and even classpath.

I have project CacheProject which contains CachePackage as a package which has CacheMain.java class. This CacheMain class contains a public method getName() which should return me a value of one of the varible there as string.

I have also created jar for the respective CacheProject  and added to classpath of another project CacheConsumer1. also I have added project CacheProject to Right click on CacheConsumer1 -> properties -> java build path -> projects.

[image]

Still I am neither able to access CacheMain nor getName() method of it:

[image]

also I am not able to access anything from the CachePackage:

[image]

Please help with it guys if anybody has already worked with something like this. Because none of the earlier answer posted in this stackOverFlow post is working for my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything would be easier if you would learn to use Maven or Gradle in order to build your projects and define dependencies. But in Eclipse you can just open both projects, then go to the project properties of project `CacheConsumer1` and set project `CacheProject` as a build path dependency:

[image: Java build path - add project dependency]
This will also lead to `CacheConsumer1` automatically being rebuilt as soon as there are changes in `CacheProject`.

---

**Update:** I just noticed in your screenshot that `CacheProject` has no `src` folder or any other folder marked as source folder (the folder icon with the little parcel in it). Maybe you just start over, create a new Java project with default Eclipse folder structure and move the class or classes over to that project, creating your Java packages and classes inside the `src` folder.

Comment: I did try same i.e. the building project properties and build path dependency... but still not working.

Comment: Then you are probably making a mistake. Besides, you might want to learn about Java class and package naming conventions. `CachePackage` looks like a class name more than a package name. Just use lower-case letters and name it something like `cache` or `com.mycompany.myproject.cache`. Anyway, if you can zip both project directories from your workspace and upload them to somewhere, I can download them and have a look.

Comment: Okay, got it. You have no designated source folder. Please read my updated answer.

Comment: One more hint for you as a new SO user: Please be careful to choose the right tags for your questions. You chose _multithreading_, _spring-boot_, _concurrency_, _spring-aop_. The question is completely unrelated to all of these. Thus, I changed your tags to _java_, _eclipse_ for you.

Comment: Thanks sure I will take care

Comment: You didn't say if my updated answer solved your problem or not. If so, please upvote and accept it. If not, please do as I said and upload a complete zip of your two projects or push them to GitHub, so I can take a look. I don't like to speculate any further and rely on screenshots as an information source.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I really appreciate it. About earlier modified answers , In spite of all these changes I am not able to work out with projects level method/variable sharing. I will share my code on git and will share link here in further comments soon.

Comment: Not just the code, the Eclipse project settings too, please. Thanks. 

Comment: I named the packages into both producer and consumer projects. and tried to use jar of producer cacheProject into CacheConsumer. and it worked! :)  later i created new projects pair of producer-consumer with same way as you said using packages name. and used add project of properties. it worked. thanks!

Comment: I have upvoted you for your valuable answers but since my profile reputation is less than 15, it's not displayed.

Comment: But you have not accepted the answer (click on the grey check mark, making it green) in order to close the question.

Comment: thanks... I am new so i hardly know these things. :)